# How to serialize to java.util.List and java.util.Map with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Is it possible to serialize Java objects to lists and maps with Jackson library directly? I mean not to `String`, not to `byte[]`, but to `java.util.Map` and `java.util.List`.

This might be helpful when filtering out unnecessary fields dynamically.

I can do it in two steps, by first converting to `String`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
DTO dto = new DTO();
DTO[] dtos = {dto};
mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto), Object.class); // Map
mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(dtos), Object.class); // List
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `convertValue` method:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = objectMapper.convertValue(new Person(), Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

It works as well for `Object.class` as a target type:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object map = objectMapper.convertValue(new Person(), Object.class);
Object array = objectMapper.convertValue(Collections.singleton(new Person()), Object.class);
System.out.println(map);
System.out.println(array);
```

prints:

```
{name=Rick, lastName=Bricky}
[{name=Rick, lastName=Bricky}]
```

Comment: `mapper.convertValue(object, Object.class)` also works.

Comment: @VytenisBivainis, It is a little bit `counterintuitive` but if you need this level of abstraction and it works for you why not. I will add it to an answer. I always used `Map` and `List` as target classes but today I learned it works as expected for `Object.class` as well. Thanks, I learned something new too!