# How do I store contents of a parsed JSON message into string variables based on keywords?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I need help storing text from a parsed `JSON` message into variables based on keywords. What I mean by this is, I have a `JSON` message that I have parsed once, and within that message, it returns things like:

```
Name: Kobe Bryant<br/>
Company: Lakers<br/>
Email: kobe@lakers.com<br/>
etc.
```

I want to be able to look at this block of test, see that it says "Name: Kobe Bryant," and store Kobe Bryant into a string variable called "name" and so on. How can I handle this?

```
public class ParseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String name;
        String company;
        String email;
        String phoneNumber;
        String projectType;
        String contactBy;
        String timeFrame;
        String message;

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

        MainParser mp = mapper.readValue(new File("/Users/kane/VersionControl/LambdaTest/src/InfoBox.txt"), MainParser.class);

        if ("blah".equals(mp.getTopicArn())) {
            //Send to proposal table
            System.out.println(mp.getSubject());
            System.out.println(mp.getMessage());
        } else if ("blah blah".equals(mp.getTopicArn())) {
            //Send to infoBox table
            System.out.println(mp.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The `JSON` that I'm parsing is:

```
{
 "Subject" : "Proposal Request (sent Wed May 22 2019 14:47:49 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time))",
 "Message" : "Name: Kobe Bryant\nCompany: Lakers\nEmail: kobe@lakers.com"
}
```

Here's the `POJO` class:

```
private String Subject;
private String Message;

public String getSubject() {
    return Subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    Subject = subject;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    Message = message;
}
```

Comment: `"Message"` key does not contains valid `JSON` object. But just a text which looks like this: `"Name: Kobe Bryant\nCompany: Lakers\nEmail: kobe@lakers.com"`. So, every `key-value` pair is separated by new line. Could you confirm that?

Comment: @MichałZiober Sorry for such a late response, but yes, you are correct. Every line is separated by new line.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `JSON` payload where one of values contains data in `key:value` pairs split by new line `\n`. We need to create two `POJO` classes: `Message` for root `JSON` and `Person` - internal person data. These two classes could look like this:

```
class Message {

    private String subject;
    private String message;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class Person {

    private String name;
    private String company;
    private String email;

    // ... more properties

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

We can parse your `JSON` payload as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);

        Message message = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Message.class);
        String[] lines = message.getMessage().split("\n");

        Map<String, String> properties = Stream.of(lines)
                .map(i -> i.split(":"))
                .filter(i -> i.length == 2)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i[0].trim(), i -> i[1].trim()));

        Person person = mapper.convertValue(properties, Person.class);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Above example prints for your `JSON` payload:

```
Person{name='Kobe Bryant', company='Lakers', email='kobe@lakers.com'}
```

As you can see, we created `Map` from internal data and used [convertValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method to convert `Map` to `Person` class.

See also:

1. [Java 8 – Convert List to Map](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/)
2. [How to deserialize a Map into POJO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447611/how-to-deserialize-a-mapstring-object-into-pojo/25447884#25447884)
3. [How to serialize to java.util.List and java.util.Map with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250969/how-to-serialize-to-java-util-list-and-java-util-map-with-jackson/55251009#55251009)

Comment: Thank you! Trying this now.